# How to know the history of changes made with Motherboards in ubuntu?

Tags: server, kubuntu, mac

I am working on Ubuntu OS.

Initially my pc configuration was Intel core 2 duo 3.0GH with 320 GB HDD. After some times, my friend changed the motherboard with lower version of configuration without changing the HDD.

Still the Ubuntu OS is working fine and all data is safe. I want to know that from where I would know the previous MAC address(the machines physical address)? 
Does the system keep any log file in Hard disk ? If yes, then how to know?

please help

Answer (score 0):

If the machine is using DHCP to obtain an IP address, you should be able to find it in the syslog if it wasn't too long ago.  Open a terminal and type

```
sudo zgrep "dhclient: Listening on" /var/log/syslog*
```

You will see a listing of all the MAC addresses and interfaces that dhclient has listened on.  The oldest ones have the highest number in the name of the file (e.g. syslog.8.gz), but the lines should be timestamped anyways.

Comment: Yes the machine is using dhclient.. For how many old days will it show ?

Comment: Actually my machine is obtaining IP from DHCP (WAN), Will it work?

Comment: It looks like the default for Ubuntu is to keep 4 weeks of backlogs.

Comment: Still I am unable to fetch data .. kindly help

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you are having trouble with.

Comment: I want to know that how Will I come to know the previous details of MAC Address, mother board configurations(Processor details etc) in ubuntu OS once the motherboard is changed? I mean, Is there any place where these type of data is stored by system ? If it is there , please help me . I shall be obliged to u ..

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.  I gave you specific instructions about how to find this info, and you just say "Still I am unable to fetch data".  Did you have trouble with the instructions I gave you?